# jQuery scripting image in listview

Tags: jquery, ajax, list, class, mobile

What's wrong with this code:

```
$.each(items, function(i, item) {
                $('<li />').append(
                    $('<a />').attr('data-index', i).attr('href', '#').append(
                        $('<img />').text('src=',item.imageurl), // THIS LINE
                        $('<h3 />').text(item.title).addClass('ui-li-heading'),
                        $('<p />').text(item.subtitle).addClass('ui-li-desc')
                    )
                ).appendTo($listElem).trigger('create');
            });
```

I can't see any image footage. Heading and Description work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('<img />').text('src=',item.imageurl), // THIS LINE
```

should be

```
$('<img />').attr('src',item.imageurl), // THIS LINE
```